# Inherit @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN") from parent route or controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller `AdminController`, which has a route of `/admin`. I'm securing access to it using `@IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")`.

My idea was that the controller template would link to another controller i.e `UserController`.

So `UserController` would have a route of `/admin/user` which I'd also like to secure for only `ROLE_ADMIN` users.

Is there a way I can indicate to `UserController` to inherit the same restrictions as `AdminController`?

`AdminController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'AdminController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

`UserController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/admin/user")
 */
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="user_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
            'users' => $userRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="user_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
        }

        return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(User $user): Response
    {
        return $this->render('user/show.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, User $user): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
        }

        return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, User $user): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$user->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you taken a look at firewall access_control configuration? @IsGranted really is a very local approach, firewall access_control can make broaders strokes. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html